# Using "match" as a method name in Python class

Tags: python, naming-conventions, keyword

I have a Python class `Shape`, which can perform matching. I called the corresponding method `match`:

```
class Shape:
...
    def match(self, image):
```

and it is working, as far as I can tell. Is there a reason to avoid using `match` keyword as a method name and substitute it by a different word at the cost of semantic clarity, i.e. any situation where this class would not behave as expected?

Comment: Do you mean because of [the `match` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement)? As it says there `match` is a _soft keyword_. Preventing attributes named `match` would break, amongst other things, [the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match); it can still be used as a variable or argument name too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know the distinction between soft and "hard" keywords.